# What is proc and method in react javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning about HOC from this [article](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.nvtexdenl) but have not see `proc` and `method` before. What does those refer to?

```
function refsHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class RefsHOC extends React.Component {
    proc(wrappedComponentInstance) {
      wrappedComponentInstance.method()
    }

    render() {
      const props = Object.assign({}, this.props, {ref: this.proc.bind(this)})
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this.proc` refers to the method

```
proc(wrappedComponentInstance) {
  wrappedComponentInstance.method()
}
```

---

`wrappedComponentInstance.method()` is a just an example of how to call an arbitrary method on the wrapped component. The article says:

> In the following example we explore how to access instance methods and the instance itself of the *WrappedComponent* via *refs*

---

So, neither has anything to do with React specifically.

Comment: what does proc do? does it just return a reference to the method()? I have never heard of it or read about it before.

Comment: You are overthinking this. `RefsHOC` is a class. That class defines a method `proc`. An instance of the class can access the method via `this.proc`. Here is another simplified example: `class Foo { bar() {} baz() { this.bar() }`. Every instance of `Foo` will have the methods `bar` and `baz`. `baz` calls `bar` via `this.bar()`. Or even more simplified: `var foo = {bar() {}, baz() { this.bar() }}`. `foo` is an object with two methods. `foo.baz()` will also call `foo.bar` via `this.bar()`.

Comment: *"what does proc do?"* It's there in the code: `wrappedComponentInstance.method()`. It calls the `method` method on the argument that is passed in.

Comment: sorry I totally thought it was some weird javascript native operation, didn't stop to think it was a custom method

Comment: @stackjlei you're not the only one—found this thread while searching for the same answer! Never occurred to me it might just be a named function...

Comment: I thought the same thing too

Answer (score 4):

I came across this same article and was confused at first. I broke it out into ES6 syntax to make things clearer for users that are also confused.

```
export default WrappedComponent =>
   class extends Component {

     //Proc function that gets called
     proc = wrappedComponentInstance => {
        wrappedComponentInstance.method()
     }

    render() {
        const props = { ...this.props, ...{ ref: this.proc } }
        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    }
}
```